# extracting data from website using beautifulsoup4 and parse into csv

Tags: csv, parsing, beautifulsoup

I just started with python and I am a bit lost. Basically the problem is that I want to extract the data from this website: "https://www.berufsstart.de/unternehmen/bundesland/baden-wuerttemberg-top-100.php" and get all 100 companies with their employees count and their city parsed into an csv. I never worked with beautifulsoup before and every tutorial I found only uses simple code. I would share my code but It is not much and more trying to understand the concept. I dont expect a 100% finished solution, more a explanation on how to start this project.

thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


r = requests.get(
    "https://www.berufsstart.de/unternehmen/bundesland/baden-wuerttemberg-top-100.php")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

numbers = []
names = []
cities = []
for num in soup.findAll("div", class_="col-sm-2"):
    num = num.get_text(strip=True, separator=",")
    if num:
        numbers.append(num.split(',')[1])
for name in soup.findAll("strong", class_="h2"):
    names.append(name.text)
for city in soup.findAll("div", class_="col-sm-5 infobereich"):
    cities.append(city.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ").split(" ")[1])

with open("kas.csv", 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Name", "City", "Number"])
    for a, b, c in zip(names, cities, numbers):
        writer.writerow([a, b, c])

print("Done")
```

Output: [view-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/1a17c32b9de43981e87be5e470583fca/kas.csv)